# invalid request BLR at offset 163

Tags: firebird2.5

I have the following error in the Firebird Database. version 2.5.2

```
invalid request BLR at offset 163 
function F_ENCODEDATE is not defined     
module name or entrypoint could not be found

Error while parsing procedure GETMONTHSBYYEAR's BLR
```

Until last week everything was functioning correctly. This UDF exists on the disk. How can I debug this problem? Anyone can help me to sort out this problem.

PS: What I did so far to fix:

- Backup / restore - no result. (any structure problem is fixed in my opinion after a BK/Restore).
- Comment all dependencies, drop UDF function, recreate again - no result.

Comment: Either the UDF definition no longer exists in the database, the UDF dll is inaccessible for the server (eg due to permissions, or the UDF restriction config in `firebird.conf`), or you have installed a 64 bit version of Firebird and your UDF is 32 bit (or vice versa).

Comment: the correct answer in my case is the wrong install 32 bit on a machine with 64 bit of the UDF. tks

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potential problems could be that he UDF dll is inaccessible for the server (eg due to permissions, or the UDF restriction config in `firebird.conf`), or you have installed a 64 bit version of Firebird and your UDF is 32 bit (or vice versa), so Firebird cannot load the DLL.

Comment: That's correct. I have Windows 10 64 bit and i had to put the gds32.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64