# UDF Firebird function STRTOINT is not defined in query even if its listed in RDB$FUNCTIONS

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0

I'm trying to run a SQL query in my Firebird database. I've restored a backup in my local development environment.

My error is the following:

```
echo "SELECT STRTOINT('3') FROM MyTable;" | isql-fb /var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/dbname.fdb
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 39000
invalid request BLR at offset 36
-function STRTOINT is not defined
-module name or entrypoint could not be found
```

To check if the function exists i run this:

```
echo 'SELECT RDB$FUNCTION_NAME FROM RDB$FUNCTIONS;' | isql-fb /var/lib/firebird/3.0/data/dbname.fdb  | grep STRTOINT
STRTOINT
```

How to call the function correctly? Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the UDF is defined in the database does not mean the UDF **exists**. UDFs require both a definition in the database, and a native library (.dll/.so) on disk that contains the code for the UDF function.

The error means that either

- The UDF does not exist in any of the libraries found,
- Firebird has no permission to read the library,
- The folder containing the library is not defined in `firebird.conf` (setting `UdfAccess`)
- The UDF library is 32 bit and Firebird is 64 bit (or vice versa)

See also [invalid request BLR at offset 163](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880817/invalid-request-blr-at-offset-163)

Firebird itself has no UDF called `STRTOINT`, so you need to find out which third-party library this is, and install it correctly.

Comment: Is there any way to "debug" this. Any log level in Firebird to see which of those cases causes the error?

Comment: @NepomukFrädrich I don't think there is, but I hardly ever use UDF, so I don't know for sure. You might want to consider replacing that UDF with cast or one of the built-ins (depending on what strtoint really does), or maybe write a stored function hat does the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've no access to the real usage of the `STRTOINT` method call. It's inside a other function used by third-party software. I'm just a "consumer" of this DB. For development purposes I've created a backup and created a local instance of this Firebird DB.

Comment: @NepomukFrädrich Did you also copy all UDF libraries?

Comment: No, just used `gbak`. I don't think this would work in my scenario (the production Firebird runs on Windows - my development Firebird server is a Ubuntu machine).

Comment: @NepomukFrädrich Well, that would explain why you don't have the right UDF on your system. You need to have an appropriate library with the UDF on your system, otherwise it won't work. If you only have a Windows version of the UDF library, you will need to run the Firebird server on Windows.

Comment: ...or to run Windows Firebird on Linux+WinE - but best of all is to use this opportunity to just get rid of UDF

Comment: ...or to reverse-engineer the function and make his own UDF (or in FB 3 an SQL function) mimicking the missed UDF behavior. Now, @NepomukFrädrich has to show a full definition of the function. chances are that was one of well-known de facto standard libraries

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do the following?

```
CAST(MyVarcharCol AS INT)
```

Read more: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq139/

Comment: This may have difference in corner cases. For example the function name suggests `Delphi` origin, with the HEX format being like `$1234ABCD`, while in C-derived languages it would be `0x1234ABCD` and in Basic it would be `&H1234ABCD`, in Intel assembler `1234ABCDh` and so forth.

Comment: In my particular case, the `STRTOINT` function is called from inside a other function I've no direct access / modification access.